# Converting rep movsd to to C without memcpy

Tags: assembly, decompilation, c, functions

So I am currently in the stages of creating binexact version of functions in decompiled code. I noticed that in this function the `rep movsd` is called and logically this is translated as Qmemcpy/memcpy when transformed to Pcode in IDA. In order to bin exact this , I cannot use memcopy because a function will be called and the code wont be bin exact. Is there a way to try to force the use of `rep movsd` ? I understand this is somewhat compiler dependent, but I was thinking I could write this differently to force the same effect.

**C code This is what I need to change to match original assembly**

```
BOOL NetSendCmdReq2(BYTE bCmd, BYTE mast, BYTE pnum, TCmdGItem *p)
{
    DWORD ticks;
    TCmdGItem cmd;

    memcpy(&cmd, p, sizeof(cmd));
    cmd.bCmd = bCmd;
    cmd.bPnum = pnum;
    cmd.bMaster = mast;

    ticks = GetTickCount();
    if (!cmd.dwTime) {
        cmd.dwTime = ticks;
    } else if (ticks - cmd.dwTime > 5000) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    multi_msg_add((BYTE *)&cmd.bCmd, sizeof(cmd));

    return TRUE;
}
```

**Compare Assembly: (This is what the C above compiles to)**

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
sub esp, 0x28
push ebx
push esi
push 0x26
lea eax, [ebp-0x28]
push [ebp+0x10]
mov bl, dl
mov esi, ecx
push eax
call <imm_fn> <------ This should be rep movsd rather than a call.
mov al, [ebp+0x0C]
add esp, 0x0C
mov [ebp-0x26], al
mov al, [ebp+0x08]
test esi, esi
mov [ebp-0x28], bl
mov [ebp-0x27], al
jnz $+0xF
and [ebp-0x0E], esi
mov dl, 0x26
lea ecx, [ebp-0x28]
call <imm_fn>
jmp $+0x25
call [<indir_fn>]
cmp dword ptr [ebp-0x0E], 0x00
jnz $+0x5
mov [ebp-0x0E], eax
jmp $+0xA
sub eax, [ebp-0x0E]
cmp eax, 0x1388
jnle $+0xA
mov dl, 0x26
lea ecx, [ebp-0x28]
call <imm_fn>

pop esi
pop ebx
leave
ret 0x0C
```

**Origional Assembly : This is what should be matched .**

```
push ebp 
mov ebp, esp
sub esp, 0x28

push esi
mov esi, [ebp+0x10]
push edi
mov eax, ecx
push 0x09
lea edi, [ebp-0x28]
pop ecx
rep movsd < ----- Notice this doesn't make an actual call.
mov cl, [ebp+0x0C]
movsw  
mov [ebp-0x26], cl
mov cl, [ebp+0x08]
test eax, eax
mov [ebp-0x28], dl
mov [ebp-0x27], cl
jnz $+0xF
and [ebp-0x0E], eax
mov dl, 0x26
lea ecx, [ebp-0x28]
call <imm_fn>
jmp $+0x25
call [<indir_fn>]
cmp dword ptr [ebp-0x0E], 0x00
jnz $+0x5
mov [ebp-0x0E], eax
jmp $+0xA
sub eax, [ebp-0x0E]
cmp eax, 0x1388
jnle $+0xA
mov dl, 0x26
lea ecx, [ebp-0x28]
call <imm_fn>
pop edi
pop esi

leave
ret 0x0C
```

Comment: movsd intrinsic suits you? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/movsd?view=msvc-160

Comment: Inline attribute will remove the function call and insert rep mov instruction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a sample code that will emit rep movsd instead of memcpy()  function

the src const char * is deliberately kept large enough to avoid unrolling and using  simple mov [dest++] ,const

source

```
:\>cat memcopin.cpp
#include <memory.h>
#pragma intrinsic( memcpy )

char *src ="\
I am Source And I Will be truncated by memcpy\n\
I am Source And I Will be truncated by memcpy\n";

char dest[128];

int main(void) {
    memcpy(dest,src,64);
    return 0;
}
```

compiled and linked with vscommunity 2017 dev cmd prompt as x86 on x86

```
:\>cl /Zi /W4 /analyze /EHsc /Od /nologo memcopin.cpp /link /release
memcopin.cpp
```

executed under debugger cdb.exe(windbg console) awk is not a necessity it is there to get only relevent output and awk is availble for windows x86 and x64

```
:\>cdb -c "g memcopin!main;uf .;pt;da /c 64 poi(src);da /c 64 dest;q" memcopin.exe |awk "/Reading/,/quit:/"

0:000> cdb: Reading initial command 'g memcopin!main;uf .;pt;da /c 64 poi(src);da /c 64 dest;q'
disassembly  of main()

memcopin!main:
01291000 55              push    ebp
01291001 8bec            mov     ebp,esp
01291003 56              push    esi
01291004 57              push    edi
01291005 b910000000      mov     ecx,10h
0129100a 8b3500902d01    mov     esi,dword ptr [memcopin!src (012d9000)]
01291010 bfe0992d01      mov     edi,offset memcopin!dest (012d99e0)
01291015 f3a5            rep movs dword ptr es:[edi],dword ptr [esi]
01291017 33c0            xor     eax,eax
01291019 5f              pop     edi
0129101a 5e              pop     esi
0129101b 5d              pop     ebp
0129101c c3              ret
src 
012d0190  "I am Source And I Will be truncated by memcpy.I am Source And I Will be truncated by memcpy."
dest
012d99e0  "I am Source And I Will be truncated by memcpy.I am Source And I "
quit:
```

Comment: Your idea works. But it wasn't the solution for me . Apparently the original developers just made a pointer to the struct to copy it.

Comment: cmd = *pcmditem; instead of memcpy .